# Cannot Connect to Server at 'localhost' when Set the MySQL Root Password

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up the MAMP development environment in MAC OS X Yosemite(10.10.2).

I am following this **[tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)**.

But problems happen when I try to set MySQL root password using command **`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'yourpasswordhere'`**. 
I get a error message :

> ```
> "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost'
>     failed error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
>     (using password: NO)'".
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAMP PRO has a great UI ...

[image]

... as for MAMP without the PRO, I don't remember. But I think it required adding MAMP's SQL to your PATH.

Comment: Thx for your help! I am wondering does it mean i can use MAMP pro for my development environment instead of using the terminal. If so, how can i run my php files(without framework)on the localhost? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if u use mamp then why to set the password from the trmnl ,u can easily set it up through mamp it self

[image]